# Conditional NSString constants

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, constants

I am declaring table view cell XIBs names as NSString constants. There are separate XIBs for iPad and iPhone and I want to refer both version of XIBs using the same name of constant but values differ.

BaseViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

extern NSString * const FileCell;
extern NSString * const FolderCell;
```

BaseViewController.m

```
#import "BaseViewController.h"

//I am sure that this cannot be done 
//since I cannot check device type at preprocessing time/compile time

#if IS_IPAD_DEVICE// device check, not viable
NSString * const FileCell = @"FileCell";
NSString * const FolderCell = @"FolderCell";
#else
NSString * const FileCell = @"FileCell~iPhone";
NSString * const FolderCell = @"FolderCell~iPhone";
#endif

//I don't want to declare separate constants with different names for iPhone table view cells. 
//I want to use same name of constants but the string values are different for iPad and iPhone. 

@implementation BaseViewController

-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.collectionView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:FileCell bundle:nil] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:FileCell];
    [self.collectionView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:FolderCell bundle:nil] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:FolderCell];

}
```

Many other files and child controllers also uses these constants.
Any idea how can I accomplish this thing. I don't want to use properties and override their getters. Some elegant solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this with an `#ifdef` because the same executable can be used on both iPhones and iPads.

But you don't need an `#ifdef` anyway, because iOS automatically loads different resource files (including XIB files) for iPhone and iPad, if you name your resources properly.  This behavior is documented in the [*Resource Programming Guide*](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000051i-CH1-SW1).

Specifically, on an iPhone, when you ask for `FileCell.xib`, it will automatically load `FileCell~iphone.xib` instead if that resource exists. On an iPad, it will automatically load `FileCell~ipad.xib` instead, if that resource exists.

Note that iOS uses a **case-sensitive** filesystem, unlike Mac OS X. So all you need to do is rename `FileCell~iPhone.xib` to `FileCell~iphone.xib`, and likewise for your other xibs. Note the **lower-case** `p`.

Comment: I went through the doc and this looks promising. Let me try it.

Comment: Thanks Rob! Yes, it is working and is the most elegant way!

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by several ways like :

1. Use one xibs with struts/springs without auto layout OR Using auto layout to make enable for all screen sizes.
2. Other Way you have to set values for NSString on start of the screen by using properties or global variable.

ViewController.h

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController

NSString * FileCell;
NSString * FolderCell;

@end
```

ViewController.m

```
@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    if ( UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad )
    {
        FileCell = @"FileCell";
        FolderCell = @"FolderCell";

    }else{
        FileCell = @"FileCell~iPhone";
        FolderCell = @"FolderCell~iPhone";
    }
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
@end
```

Comment: These are not constants and often this can lead to some head scratching issues since values can be changed at any time and there is no compile time error.

Comment: One more thing, since you are defining these variables at runtime so if some other class is using these variables, the code will not compile because these variables remain undefined.

Comment: to use these variable in whole application we can use these as class level variable (static) , get these variables with class name in any other class or can use a manager class extend by nsobject for get and set values for these variables

Answer (score 0):

import

```
 @interface ViewController : UIViewController

 extern NSString * FileCell; extern NSString * FolderCell;

 @end
```

## import "ViewController.h"

```
 @interface ViewController ()

 @end

 @implementation ViewController

 (void)viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];

   if ( UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad ) { 
          FileCell = @"FileCell";  
          FolderCell = @"FolderCell";


   }
  else
    { 
     FileCell = @"FileCell~iPhone"; FolderCell = @"FolderCell~iPhone"; 
     } 

      [self.collectionView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:FileCell bundle:nil] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:FileCell];

       [self.collectionView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:FolderCell bundle:nil] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:FolderCell];
   }


   (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning { [super didReceiveMemoryWarning]; // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated. }

  @end
```

Comment: Since you are defining these variables at runtime so if some other class is using these variables, the code will not compile because these variables remain undefined.

Answer (score 0):

In a programatic approach is not room. In the end you need the name of the cell and its identifier.

In a storyboard approach before iOS 8 we had separate storyboards for iPad and iPhone. Each of them had their own layout and thus their own cells. I think that is a more clean solution. As much we try to do over generic storyboards, an iPad has still more room to display things. Therefore stretching content as u see for Android tablet apps makes no sense.

My suggestion is, split the iPad and iPhone storyboard. They still can share the same classes. After all we had splitview long before iOS 9 in our apps.

Comment: I am having different XIBs for iPhone and iPad. Although my concern is, can a constant represent two different values by any means like preprocessor expressions etc or any other better approach.

Comment: I dont understand your question.